# wordpress issue with custom field in category using html

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using this code to add a custom field on my category page. Inside of it, I would like to use an html link like this: `<a rel="nofollow" href="my_meta_url_here" target="_blank">my_meta_name_here</a>`, but after I save it, the html becomes like this:

`<a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"my_meta_url_here\" target=\"_blank\">my_meta_name_here</a>`

How can I use html inside this and echo it (or something else) in my templates?

```
// Add the field to the Add New Category page
add_action( 'category_add_form_fields', 'taxonomy_add_new_meta_field', 10, 2 );

function taxonomy_add_new_meta_field() {
    // this will add the custom meta field to the add new term page
    ?>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="term_meta[my_meta]">Link Credit:</label>
        <input type="text" name="term_meta[my_meta]" id="term_meta[my_meta]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $term_meta['my_meta'] ) ? esc_attr( $term_meta['my_meta'] ) : ''; ?>">
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Are you using advanced custom fields?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to return your html as a string.

```php
function taxonomy_add_new_meta_field() {
    $my_meta = esc_attr($term_meta['my_meta']) ? esc_attr($term_meta['my_meta']) : '';

    // this will add the custom meta field to the add new term page
    return "<div class='form-field'>
        <label for='term_meta[my_meta]'>Link Credit:</label>
        <input type='text' name='term_meta[my_meta]' id='term_meta[my_meta]' value='{$my_meta}'>
    </div>";
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the game output? Are you sure you're not escaping this in your templare?